# In xpath how you compare text() with \r\n (line break)?

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to get the node :

//script[starts-with(text(). '\r\nvar name')]

but it seems xpath does not recognize \r\n escape characters. Any ideas how to match them?

Note: I am using html agility pack

Comment: use character entities.  \r = `&#x0d;` and \n = `&#x0a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//script[starts-with(., '&#xD;&#xA;var name')]
```

**Most often XML is *normalized* by the XML parser and there is only a single NL character left** -- therefore, if the above expression doesn't select the wanted `script` elements, try with:

```
//script[starts-with(., '&#xA;var name')]
```

**Or, this would work in both cases**:

```
//script
    [(starts-with(., '&#xD;&#xA;') or starts-with(., '&#xA;'))
   and
    starts-with(substring-after(., '&#xA;'), 'var name')
    ]
```

Comment: Dimitre's answer is of course correct. But I would question your design. Are you sure you really want to match "var name" while disallowing other preceding whitespace? I would have thought a better design was `starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'var name')`

Comment: @MichaelKay: The OP is using "HTML Agility Pack" which isn't a complete implementation of XPath 1.0 -- I wasn't aware if the HAP supports `normalize-space()`.

Comment: @MichaelKay None of the above worked. Seems like HAP do not recognize &#xA;

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Last commment was for you.

Comment: @Devela: Then this isn't an XPath issue. People who know HAP could probably offer some workaround.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev it just doesnt select the node. The workaround is using contains() but that is costly.

Comment: @Devela: `contains()` will find "var name" everywhere in the string -- not only at the start of the line. Also, how can you verify with `contains()` that the strings starts with a CRNL?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev contains() will ignore whatever is in the first characters and then return the node when it matches var name (which is at the start).

Comment: @devela: Exactly. therefore you'll accept `"XXX var name"` but you actually only need `"var name anything else following"`. This is why just `contains($yourString, 'var name')` isn't a solution at all.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev For the type of problem that solves it, but a better approach is using substring to ignore those characeters that can't be mataches \r\n (in this case)